# How to use GREATER THAN / LESS THEN as a dynamic parameter in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I am passing values like "more" and "less" as an IN "_more_less" parameter, as well as "_records_num" from PHP to a mySQL procedure, and I am wondering if this is even possible in mySQL procedure query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
CASE 
WHEN _more_less = 'more'
THEN HAVING (COUNT(*) >= _records_num OR _records_num IS NULL)
ELSE HAVING (COUNT(*) <= _records_num OR _records_num IS NULL)
END
```

or some sort of passing "more" or "less" as a value into "_more_less" parameter and having it evaluate as >= or <= in the query itself matching the logic above.

Is that possible with mySQL at all without writing IF ... THEN ... END IF statements in a procedure for each one of these scenarios, as I've already got a few IF / THEN cases and this would just complicate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either of these queries will get the results you want:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(*) cnt FROM table
GROUP BY col1
HAVING 
   (_more_less = 'more' AND (COUNT(*) >= _records_num OR _records_num IS NULL)) OR
   (_more_less = 'less' AND (COUNT(*) <= _records_num OR _records_num IS NULL))

----------------

SELECT col1 FROM
(SELECT col1, COUNT(*) cnt, 
    CASE _more_less WHEN 'more' THEN COUNT(*) >= _records_num 
         ELSE COUNT(*) <= _records_num END RES   --less
 FROM table GROUP BY col1) X
WHERE RES = 1 OR _records_num IS NULL
```

Comment: Duh, how did I not see that - was already half way there... thank you so much!